# Official AutoIt language syntax specification

Tags: syntax, autoit, language-specifications

I want to create a compiler for AutoIt, which compiles it to x86-instructions - however, I was unable to find an official syntax description of the AutoIt language (may it be in form of ANTLR-syntax-description or an official syntax tree).

Could someone point me into the right direction?

---

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/ has a section called *Language Reference*, but it is more a "how to"-guide than a formal language description and I do not know, whether it is complete or not (I do not have much experience with AutoIt itself).

Comment: Maybe this will help... [link](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/147809-wrapit/?tab=comments#comment-1048823)

Comment: [Example](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/191320-compileit-an-experimental-autoit-to-machine-code-compiler/) of such a project. `\AutoIt3\SciTE\Properties\au3.properties` and `au3.keywords.properties` may be of use.

Comment: Thank you, I did however ask a friend of mine and he provided me with a rough syntax tree of AutoIt. I am currently writing a Compiler for it myself and I will publish my syntax-tree when I have finished the project.
https://github.com/Unknown6656/AutoIt-Interpreter